# How to get values from an ArrayList from another class once it has been defined?

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I cant get my head around accessing information that I have written to an `ArrayList` in another code works. 
I have been trying to figure it out from other answers that people have gotten but I never seem to get it right.

I always seem to get the same response `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException`: Index: 0, Size: 0 . It doesn't work and I'm pretty damn sure that it is something simple and that just makes it all the more infuriating.

So in my testing project I have a getter and setter class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;    
class Values {    
    ArrayList<Double> values = new ArrayList<>();

    public ArrayList<Double> getValueList() {
        return values;
    }

    public void addValue(double price) {
        values.add(price);
    }

    public double getValue(int location) {
        return values.get(location);
    }    
}
```

Then I have another class that uses these methods to write to the `ArrayList`.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ValuesTesting {
    Values v = new Values();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ValuesTesting vT = new ValuesTesting();
        vT.addValue1();
        vT.addValue2();
        ValueTesting2 vT2 = new ValueTesting2();
        vT2.main();
    }

    private void addValue1() {
        double price = 1502.0;
        v.addValue(price);
    }

    private void addValue2() {
        double price = 1204.0;
        v.addValue(price);
    }
}
```

And then I want to read the values from my third class which has this code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class ValueTesting2 {
    Values v = new Values();
    public void main() {
        getList();
    }
    private void getList() {
        System.out.println(Double.toString(v.getValueList().get(0)));
    }
}
```

I know the naming is completely wrong but I only intended this to be a class that I could finally figure this out on, but I just cant.

Any help would be great, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating a new Values object in both classes.  Since they're different instances of the values class, they won't share data.  If you want to share the same instance, you need to pass a reference from one to the other.

The reason for the index out of bounds exception is that in your main you're trying to get index 0, but you never added any values to it, so its size is 0.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply!

Answer (score 0):

When you are doing `ValueTesting2 vT2 = new ValueTesting2();`  it will create a object 'v' of `Values` class. Now the vT2.main() will try to get the 0th element of the Arraylist of this newly created object, which is not valid.

they are both different objects. That is why you are getting this error.

You can pass your Arraylist which has the values to the constructor of ValueTesting2 and then try.

Answer (score 0):

you are not passing reference, so pass Values reference to ValueTesting2.
just do this
change `Values v = new Values();` to `static Values v = new Values();` and 
change  `vT2.main();` to  `vT2.main(v);` we are passing v as reference here.

so your complete **ValuesTesting** code will be

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

    public class ValuesTesting {
    static Values v = new Values();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ValuesTesting vT = new ValuesTesting();
        vT.addValue1();
        vT.addValue2();
        ValueTesting2 vT2 = new ValueTesting2();
        vT2.main(v);
    }
    private void addValue1() {
        double price = 1502.0;
        v.addValue(price);
    }
    private void addValue2() {
        double price = 1204.0;
        v.addValue(price);
    }

}
```